# OnChange jquery not working

Tags: jquery, function, onchange

I have the below jquery but its not calling the 'callFunction'. Can anyone pointout what is wrong

```
jQuery('[id$="my_attr_0"]').on("change", function() {
    callFunction();
        });
```

Comment: Does the element with the `id` that ends with `my_attr_0` exist in the DOM? And if so, does it exist when the page loads? Do you have any errors in the console? There's hundreds of reasons this may not work, so it's hard to give you a definitive answer without seeing more of your code

Comment: Also does the element (or childelement) raise the change-event, please share html also.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs It is not wrong if he wants to find with id-attribute that ends with that value: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: @Esko - huh weird, seems backwards, I'd just put a class on and do an each statement, but I guess if it's right it's right :) will delete my comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
jQuery(document).on("change", '[id$="my_attr_0"]', function() {
    callFunction();
});
```

Even if the specified element is not present in the DOM when this is being executed, your method will be called on change event.

Assuming that your selector is correct.

You may see it working here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfKamran/hLzwv26L/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('[id$="my_attr_0"]').on("change", function() {
    callFunction();
        });
        
 function callFunction(){
  console.log('running function');
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="check_my_attr_0">
<option> hello </option>
<option> function </option>
</select>
```

Your code is working well . please check the code snippet